# How to add a circuit layer after computing QAOA layer

Tags: qiskit, optimization, qaoa

I have used the Qiskit-based QAOA function to solve a combinatorial problem tsp, and I want to append a  circuit after the QAOA layer, is there any way to do that?

[image: STANDARD QAOA LAYER WITH APPENDED MULTIPARAMETER LAYER][Qaoa](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.minimum_eigensolvers.QAOA.html#qiskit.algorithms.minimum_eigensolvers.QAOA)

Comment: Do you mean to use output of QAOA in another circuit?

Comment: i meant that i have a circuit that i want to append after QAOA, but the problem is QAOA is implemented in the form of using a qiskit function, is there any way to append the layer after qaoa ?

Answer (score 1):

The anstaz used by QAOA is [QAOAAnsatz](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.QAOAAnsatz.html), a circuit from the circuit library. Now QAOA is a simple subclass of SamplingVQE (or the now deprecated version of VQE if you are still using the also now deprecated QAOA that uses a QuantumInstance) that sets up this specific ansatz to use. But you can take that library circuit and append/compose onto it and pass the resulting circuit as the ansatz to SamplingVQE/VQE - assuming you want to use that during the optimization process. Since using QAOAAnsatz, as the ansatz with SamplingVQE/VQE, nets out to be the same as using QAOA.